# R Shiny update selectizeinput choices based on geocoded text

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I'm trying to update the choices for selectizeinput based on geocoding in the search field. The problem is that it doesn't register I've inputted anything, but when I hardcode a fake address on the server side it works. I've tried to make the choices reactive using tidygeocoder, but it doesn't register anytime I type anything into the search field.

**Here is a reprex:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidygeocoder)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(
    "search",
    label = NULL,
    choices = "",
    multiple = FALSE,
    selected = character(0),
    options = list(allowEmptyOption = FALSE, placeholder = "SEARCH...")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  address_choices <- reactive({
    tidygeocoder::geo(
      input$search,
      method = "osm",
      limit = 5,
      full_results = TRUE
    )
  })
  
  observe({
    req(address_choices())
    current_selected <- isolate(input$search)
    updateSelectizeInput(
      session,
      "search",
      choices = address_choices()$display_name,
      selected = current_selected,
      server = TRUE
    )
  })
  
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Result:**

It shows nothing no matter what I type in.

[image]

**Hardcoded Address**

The hardcoded version shows the intended result

```
  address_choices <- reactive({
    tidygeocoder::geo(
      "110 Susan",
      method = "osm",
      limit = 5,
      full_results = TRUE
    )
  })
```

**Hardcoded Results**

The drop down shows what should happen when I type "110 Susan"

[image]

I've also tried to include if else statements so that it doesn't run when input$search is blank (Which is the default), but that doesn't work. Maybe I shouldn't be using a reactive statement? I'm not quite sure. It just doesn't register input$search after I type.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `input$search` is not populated when you are typing the text. Since it is `selectizeInput`, the value is only filled when any dropdown option is selected so `tidygeocoder::geo` function is never called.

Based on help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66187509/3962914) post , we can use the javascript function to capture the text while we are typing and use it to get the address.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidygeocoder)

js <- '
      $(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
        minChars = 4;
        tag1 = document.activeElement.getAttribute("id");
        val1 = document.activeElement.value;
        if (tag1 == "search-selectized") {
          if (Math.sign(val1.length +1 - minChars) == 1) {
            obj = { "val": val1 };
            Shiny.onInputChange("valueEntered", obj);
          }
        }
      });'
      
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$script(js),
  selectizeInput(
    "search",
    label = NULL,
    choices = "",
    multiple = FALSE,
    selected = character(0),
    options = list(allowEmptyOption = FALSE, placeholder = "SEARCH...")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  address_choices <- reactive({
    req(input$valueEntered$val)
    tidygeocoder::geo(
      input$valueEntered$val,
      method = "osm",
      limit = 5,
      full_results = TRUE
    )
  })
  
  observe({
    req(address_choices())
    current_selected <- isolate(input$search)
    updateSelectizeInput(
      session,
      "search",
      choices = address_choices()$display_name,
      selected = current_selected,
      server = TRUE
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]